# how to get into [FromBody]Guid[] use ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am using WAP API, but don't know how to use ajax connect into the aaa method. Please help. same the ajax method cannot match [FromBody]Guid[] Ids, but how

```
    [Route("aaa")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult aaa(Guid teamId, [FromBody]Guid[] Ids)
```

javascript

```
                var routeIds = new Array();  
                routeIds.push('EEBEEEDF-41F2-4931-41F2-362DDDDDD06'); 
                routeIds.push('EEBEEEDF-41F2-41F2-41F2-362DDDDDDD06'); 
                routeIds.push('EEBEEEDF-41F2-41F2-41F2-362DDDDDDD06'); 
                routeIds.push('EEBEEEDF-41F2-41F2-41F2-362DDDDDDD06'); 

                var team =  { id: "EEBEEEDF-41F2-41F2-41F2-362DDDDDDD06" }; 
                var tmp = JSON.stringify({ teamId: "EEBEEEDF-41F2-41F2-41F2-362DDDDDDD06", '': routeIds });
                    var path = GlobalData.url + "api/Event/UpdateRouteEnrollments";
                     $http({
                       method: 'POST',
                       url: path,
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                       dataType: "json",
                       data: JSON.stringify(tmp)
                       }).
                      success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                          $scope.hide(); 
                          FeedStorage.save({ "id": data.TeamId, "Route": "0CE0F3C9-BB1E-4931-98F3-362DDE7BD406" });
                          $scope.setPlatform('team'); 
                      }).
                      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                          $scope.hide();
                          alert('An error occured:' + status);
                      });
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Looks like you should have a look at your server and see if the resource you are requesting is actually there.